# Why is it true that there are no resonances for Schrodinger operator when dimension is $\geq 5$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

For a Schrodinger operator $H=-\Delta+V$, we say that the zero is a resonance of $H$ if the quation $Hu=0$ has a solution $u\notin L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $(1+|x|)^{-1-\epsilon}u\in{L^2}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

My question is that  if $n \geq 5$ or $V\geq 0$, then how to show that $H$ does not admit zero resinance.
I think it may related to the fact that the fundamental solution of $-\Delta$ ($|x|^{2-n}$,$n\geq 3$) is in $L^2$ near $\infty$ when $n \geq 5$, but I don't know how to continue.

Comment: If $u$ is in $L^1$, then by Young's inequality we can conclude $u$ is $L^2$ for $u = \Gamma*(Vu)$.